# How do I scroll to current commit in GitExtensions?

Tags: git-extensions

I'm working with a big repository with many branches. I'm on some historical branch but I scrolled away from the commit row in the UI and now I can't find it. Is there a command or shortcut how to scroll back to the commit where HEAD is currently pointing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in Navigate menu under Go to current revision.

[image]